# Hide a row based on cell value with a switch "Data Validation" -> List of items

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I found a script that hides a row by a value. I need a script that works the same way, but I need to be able to switch between different values. In my case, I have several locations and I want to show either all locations/rows or each location/value separately, depending on a cell value of each row. The value can be chosen by a "Data Validation" -> List of items.

```
/** 
* TITLE:
*     Hide a row if a value is inputted. 
*/

//**GLOBALS**
// Sheet the data is on.
var SHEET = "D&D Miniatures";
// The value that will cause the row to hide. 
var VALUE = "Yes";
// The column we will be using 
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 6

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //Ensure on correct sheet.
  if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();

    //Ensure we are looking at the correct column.
    if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
      //If the cell matched the value we require,hide the row. 
      if(cellValue == VALUE){
        activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
      };
    };
  };
}
```